# Docker change directory in CMD command

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm trying to use docker for a firebase project, for firebase the `package.json` is in a sub folder called functions. I'm using the node:alpine image.

In my Dockerfile, I need to cd into the functions directory then run `npm run start`. How do I do this, please?

I have tried CMD [ "cd", "functions", ";", "npm", "run", "serve" ], I got this error `/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec: line 8: cd: not found`

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR '/app'

RUN npm install -g firebase-tools

COPY functions/package*.json functions/

RUN cd functions && npm install && cd ..

COPY . .

CMD [ "cd", "functions", ";", "npm", "run", "serve" ]
```

Comment: That's because there is no external "cd" executable; it's a built-in shell command.  When using `[]`, the command is being executed directly, not via a shell.  That also means that the ";" would be passed as a parameter and not be interpreted as a command separator.  Basically, you tried the equivalent of
`/bin/cd function \; npm run serve`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have the dockerfile under control, simply add a line BEFORE CMD:

```
WORKDIR '/functions'
```

Answer (score 9):

the correct way is to use workdir:

```
WORKDIR /functions
CMD [ "npm", "run", "serve" ]
```

or just use:

```
CMD [ "/bin/sh" , "-c" , "cd /functions && npm run serve" ]
```

Comment: I got this error while running with "/functions": can't cd to /functions: No such file or directory, but using "functions" works just fine.

Comment: Your data are in /app/functions. Take a look at the the workdir and copy commands in your dockerfile

Comment: `CMD cd /functions && npm run serve` is equivalent to the last line (Docker in fact expands it to an identical form).